# Auto detect proxy settings if not set on system

Tags: c#, proxy, network-programming

There are a few questions on here already that deal with finding system defaults and using those. Those help give my app a "Use system defaults" option, but I occasionally work with users who don't even know their system is behind a proxy (and perhaps have a less-than-capable IT staff) so therefore they might not even have any proxy settings on their system.

How can I go about auto-detecting a proxy (if at all possible)? I haven't found a post that could adequately help and the MDSN isn't helping much either...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to check if the proxy settings are enabled or not, and get it's settings. you can use the following code (VB.Net) that can easily converted to C# that enables / disables the proxy and sets the proxy value. In general, you can use the registry to achieve it:

```
   Private Sub Enable_Proxy(ByVal Proxyset As String)
       Dim regkeyProxy_Enable As RegistryKey
       'Registry Key Location
       regkeyProxy_Enable = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", True)
       'Change The Proxy Enable value
       regkeyProxy_Enable.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
       'Set the proxy server value
       regkeyProxy_Enable.SetValue("ProxyServer", Proxyset, RegistryValueKind.String)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Disable_Proxy()
       Dim regkeyProxy_Enable As RegistryKey
       regkeyProxy_Enable = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", True)
       'Disable The proxy
       regkeyProxy_Enable.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
   End Sub
```

You can use this example and modify it for your needs.
Please note that the following key represents the proxy setting on the Windows machine and if I remember correctly, it applied for IE and Chrome, as I recall, Firefox uses its own settings.

Liron